# How do I find Jesus in everything?

Tags: life-of-jesus, lifestyle

Life is so busy and there are so many things to do, so many problems to deal with. But I don't want to walk with God just 'sometimes', I want to see Him in everything, not just in church or when I am reading the Bible. Is there any way to that?

Comment: I am guessing this question will be closed as it's not really a good fit for a S.E. site, but here's what works for me: Look for Him in everything and you'll find Him.  Make it a habit of trying to see Him, or His hand in everything.  Looking around at creation, it's easy.  Seeing HIm in a gas pump at5 the local c-store, not so easy, but you could think of the miracle of human ingenuity, the way he designed our minds to come up with such inventions, or look for the people in need of His mercy. It really is as basic as just training your mind to look. And pray without ceasing, that helps, too.

Comment: This would make an excellent blog topic.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE Mary. I understand how this is a very real question you face and a legitimate one for any Christian to consider. However this site has a very limited range of questions that its really good for, and in this case is going to invite an almost never ending string of answers because everybody's personal journey is equally valid as an answer. At least as far as this site is concerned. Please consider us for any questions you have about Christianity that can be answered and defended with concrete references.

Comment: On a personal note, I would suggest that "not just by reading the Bible" is the wrong way to look at the Word of God and that if you change your approach to that, you will find that it shines light into every dark corner of life and in it's illumination you will start seeing Jesus work in every corner of live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mary,

One of the biggest helps I have had in this area comes from a book by John Piper called [God is the Gospel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1433502542).  In one of the chapters, I believe its Chapter 5 *Delighting in God Delighting in Us*, he discusses the idea that our pleasures don't compete with God but should draw us to God.  If a spouse gives you a wonderful & thoughtful gift, the gift is nice, but the purpose of the gift is really to draw your heart to your spouse and vice versa.  In the same way, God wants us to enjoy all his gifts, and as we enjoy them, we should be appreciating the God who gave us such wonderful things to enjoy.

The reason this helps me is because I used to sit down to a bowl of chocolate ice cream and feel guilty about how much I like the ice cream.  Now, I realize that when I sit down to the bowl of chocolate ice cream, God wants me to enjoy it.  So I enjoy it and I try to marvel at God and the grace involved both in my ability to taste and in someone's ability to craft such a wonderful dessert.

So we don't have to be either/or.  You can be mindful of God even in the midst of busyness.  So if you are having a hard (or very good) day at the office or with the kids, talk to God about your day.  Remind yourself of the promises he gave you which apply right in those situations.  Look for things to thank him for.  Recognize all the blessings he has given you and wants you to enjoy.  Another very good book which addresses this idea of communing with God in all we do is a [A Praying Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600063004) by Paul Miller.